# How to build glibc with reduced size?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, glibc, lib

I'm trying to download glibc 2.23 sources and build them on my Ubuntu system. 
I need to build that specific version from sources for getting modified version of glibc customized for my research, and it will be used only within my research apps using the loader environment variables (e.g., LD_PREDLOAD or LD_LIBRARY_PATH).

But, when building it as following, I got a huge file as an output (libc.so weights about 11MB):

- download the sources to some local dir (let's say /tmp/glibc/)
- create new directory for build results (/tmp/glibc/build)
- run configure from build dir:
- < build-dir >$ ../configure --prefix=< build-dir >
  As a result, the build process will produce libc.so file under build-dir with a size of 11MB.

Is there anyway to reduce the size of the built libc.so?

p.s.

Here are my system details:
Linux version 4.4.0-93-generic (buildd@lgw01-03) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017

Thanks :)

Comment: **Why** do you want to build GNU libc from source, and why do you want to build such an old version of it?? You should **edit your question** to improve it and motivate it.

Comment: I need to build it from source for customizing libc allocator for my needs (for a research I'm doing) and the built libc will not be used as the default libc in my system (therefore, I installed it in some local build-dir folder to be used later on just on my research apps)

Comment: That should go in your question, not in a comment

Answer (score 2):

Building `glibc` from source could be a bad idea. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/395283/50557) and some comments there. Its current version is [GNU libc 2.26](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2017-08/msg00010.html)... Consider instead upgrading your entire Ubuntu distribution (Ubuntu 17.10 should be released in a few weeks, end of October 2017)

> `../configure --prefix=` *build-dir*

is a misunderstanding of the role of `--prefix` in [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf)-ed software. It relates to where the software is installed, not to its build directory.

(and I don't know exactly what should be your `--prefix` since `libc` is *so essential* to your system, perhaps it should be `--prefix=/` but you should check carefully)

> Is there any way to reduce the size of the built libc.so?

You might use (very carefully) [strip(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html), but you risk breaking your system.

And you might not care about reducing the size of `libc` since it is used (and [shared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries)) by almost every software on your Linux system!

BTW, consider also [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/). It can cohabit nicely with GNU glibc,  and in practice is used only by programs built with `musl-gcc` (provided by it).

If you are doing some research, it would be reasonable to work in a [chroot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html)-ed environment.  See also [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot). You could install with the help of `make install DESTDIR=/tmp/instmylibc` then copy that `/tmp/instmylibc` appropriately. Read [more about `autoconf`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/index.html)

PS. Be sure to at least back up your important data before such dangerous experimentations. I don't think that the size of your `libc.so` should be a significant concern. But you need to use `chroot`, perhaps with the help of [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) during installation of the `chroot`ed environment.

Comment: Thanks @Basile on your answer. As I mentioned above, I need to build customized libs for a research purpose. So, does this mean that default glibc installed on my system (which weights about 1.8MB) is stripped?